# Why Visual Studio Code Debugger is not working version 1.43.1(user setup)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-3.1

As a beginner learning .net core making a web application, I installed Visual Studio Code version 1.43.1(user setup) and trying to make run the default application comes with

> dotnet new webapi

it builds and runs in the terminal of vs code but when I goes to https://localhost:5001 in chrome it won't loads and pops up an error

> Your connection is not private

And there is one more issue! when I right click on any class, **there is no option for go to definition** and **visual studio code debugger** is seems to stuck at 47% .

Comment: "Your connection is not private" is normal, as it has many checks like [this](https://blog.lextudio.com/why-chrome-says-iis-express-https-is-not-secure-and-how-to-resolve-that-d906a183f0). You have to let it trust the self signed certificate used by your web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I finds that this all was happening because of the visual studio code debugger. And simply by clicking on setting->check for updates will solve the problem.